# javascript: new instance.constructor() equivalent to new Class()?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Given the following code

```
function Class(){}
Class.prototype=...
var instance1=new Class();
```

are the following 2 lines equivalent? is there any inconvenient to line 1 (performance, compatibility...)?

```
var instance2=new instance1.constructor();
var instance2=new Class();
```

**Edit:**

I'm especially interested in the constructor method when using inheritance: to get the final Class constructor from the base Class (I can give an example if needed)

Comment: `Class === instance1.constructor // true`

Comment: If you need to know the final class from the base class, your design might be flawed. Can you show us what you're doing there (or maybe ask a new question)?

Comment: i'm trying to implement a clone (and alter) method, a.clone(param) should return an altered version of a. The clone method is implemented in a base class. Doesn't seem right?

Comment: @klarezz: OK, but for that you should simple overwrite the `clone` method in your inheriting classes - and maybe call the base `clone` just like you do within your constructors

Comment: Isn't it too verbose to overwrite the clone method in all derived classes? are there any inconvenients to my method? that's what I'm kinda asking for

Comment: Of course it does depend on your classes whether that is necessary. Indeed, calling the common `.constructor` interface can be very convenient for the base class and is not wrong. I feared you wanted to do something like `if (this.constructor == SubClass1)` in the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent by default, but that isn't guaranteed to remain true.

When you define `Class`, `Class.prototype.constructor` is automatically defined. But if you were to write some code that changed the prototype:

```
Class.prototype = {};
```

Then Class.prototype.constructor would fall back to `Object.prototype.constructor`. Then it would correspond to `new Object()`, not `new Class()`.

To recap:

```
function Class() {}
var instance1 = new Class();

Class === instance1.constructor; // true

Class.prototype = {};
var instance2 = new Class();

instance1.constructor === instance2.constructor // false
Object === instance2.constructor // true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've given more details about my use case in the comments. Do you see any inconvenient to using the constructor method apart from the example you have provided? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations, I might have found the answer.

`constructor` usage is not recommended mostly because people usually implement inheritance doing something like:

```
Child.prototype=Object.create(Base.prototype)
```

which makes `childInstance.constructor` equal to `Base` => not what's generally expected

**Workaround**: To avoid this problem one could add the following line:

```
Child.prototype.constructor=Child
```

we then have `childInstance.constructor` equal to `Child` as expected